# Cant fix: AttributeError: startswith

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm, robotframework

Im tryng to run some tests with robot framework, ann i wanto do something after certain element is visible:

this is what i tried:

```
 Page Should Contain Element  ${TRAIN_LABEL}

 element should be visible  ${TRAIN_LABEL} 

 Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${RETRY_TIMEOUT}  ${RETRY_INTERVAL}  Wait Until Element is Visible  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
```

My TRAIN_LABEL variable:

> **${TRAIN_LABEL} =  xpath=//*[@id='trainHeader'and contains(@data-train-id,'548')]**

But when i run the test it gives me:

> AttributeError: startswith

error.

How can i fix this?

html:

```
<div class="fleetTrainCell" data-train-id="548">
                <div id="trainHeader" class="fleetTrainInfoRow fleetTrainHeader" onclick="showTrainDetails(this.getAttribute('data-train-id'))" data-train-id="548">

                    <span id="name" class="fleetTrainName">UK390002</span>  

    </div>
                <div class="fleetTrainInfoRow fleetTrainTopRow">
                    <div class="empty fleetTrainCellIcon" title=""></div>
                    <div class="fleetTrainCellIcon empty"></div>
                    <div class="fleetTrainCellIcon empty"></div>                 
                    <div class="fleetTrainCellIcon">
                    <a href="#" onclick="showTrainDetails(this.getAttribute('data-train-id'));onAddMaintenanceEventsClicked();" data-train-id="548">                       
                            <img id="addMaintEventIcon" title="Add Maintenance Events" src="/App_Themes/Alstom/Icons/datebox-icon-enabled.png" style="border-width:0px;">                       
                    </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div id="trainImageCell" title="Critical" class="fleetTrainImageCell redBackground" onclick="showTrainView(this.getAttribute('data-train-id'))" data-train-id="548" alarms="redBackground">

                    <img id="image" class="fleetTrainImage" src="../../../App_Themes/Alstom/Icons/Trains/train-Red.png" style="border-width:0px;">

</div>
            <div class="fleetTrainInfoRow fleetTrainBottomRow">            
                <div class="fleetTrainCellIcon">        
                    <a href="#" onclick="showTrainDetails(this.getAttribute('data-train-id'));showTrainSummary(this.getAttribute('data-train-id'), 'UK390002');" data-train-id="548">                
                        <img id="noInfoIcon" title="Summary" src="/App_Themes/Alstom/Icons/trains/info.png" style="border-width:0px;">  
                    </a>                      
                </div>                                  
                <div class="fleetTrainCellIcon">
                    <a id="link" class="clickableNotes" href="#" onclick="showNotes(548, 1);return(false);"><img id="img" title="Planning Note: a" class="notesExist" src="../../../App_Themes/Alstom/Icons/planning-note-new-icon.png" alt="Planning Note: a" style="border-width:0px;"></a> 
                </div>
                <div class="fleetTrainCellIcon">
                    <a id="link" class="clickableNotes" href="#" onclick="showEngineeringNotes(548);return(false);"><img id="img" title="Engineering Notes: 700" class="notesExist" src="../../../App_Themes/Alstom/Icons/engineering-note-icon-new.png" alt="Engineering Notes: 700" style="border-width:0px;"></a> 
                </div>
                <div class="maintenanceRequiredIcon  fleetTrainCellIcon" title="Anomalies Detected" onclick="showEngineeringNotes(this.getAttribute('data-train-id'), 2);" data-train-id="548">
                    <span class="trainAnomalyCount">9+</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

´´´
More detailed test:

```
*** Variables ***
&{ENGINEER_ADMIN_USER_3}          username=leonel        password=Lenel@19        email=leonel@criticalsoftware.com           language=pt-TP     language_t=pt_PT      role=system-engineer
# train
&{Train_1}      train_id=UK390001
&{Train_2}      train_id=UK390002


*** Test Cases ***
    Should be able to see train color red on UK390002
        [Tags]    DEBUG
        [Template]  Should be able to see train color red on UK390002
        ${FLEET_PAGE_URL}   ${ENGINEER_ADMIN_USER_3}    ${Train_2}



*** Keywords ***

Should be able to see train color red on UK390002
  [Arguments]  ${FLEET_PAGE_URL}  ${user}  ${train}

  Go to Login Page    ${FLEET_PAGE_URL}
  Login With Correct Credentials  ${FLEET_PAGE_URL}  ${user}
  Locate train by id  ${train}  grid
  Logout

Locate train by id
  [Arguments]  ${train}  ${type}
  Locate train  ${train}
  Validate train  ${train}  ${type}

Locate train
    [Arguments]  ${train}
    Wait Until Page Does Not Contain  ${LOADING}
    sleep  2s
    Page Should Contain Element  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
    Element Should Be Visible  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${RETRY_TIMEOUT}  ${RETRY_INTERVAL}  Wait Until Element is Visible  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
    ${Train_ID}=  Get Text  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
    log to console  train id: ${Train_ID}
    should be equal  ${train.train_id}  ${Train_ID}
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${RETRY_TIMEOUT}  ${RETRY_INTERVAL}  Get Element Attribute  ${TRAIN_IMAGE}  src
    ${Train_Color}=  Get Element Attribute  ${TRAIN_IMAGE}  src
    should be equal  ${Train_Color}  ${TRAIN_IMAGE_COLOR}
    Wait Until Page Does Not Contain  ${LOADING}
```

The test exists/stops at:

```
Page Should Contain Element  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
```

OR

```
Element Should Be Visible  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
```

OR

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds  ${RETRY_TIMEOUT}  ${RETRY_INTERVAL}  Wait Until Element is Visible  ${TRAIN_LABEL}
```

Neither of this 3 keywords work

Comment: can you post the html page source?

Comment: @Sureshmani I cant post the whole html but i updated the post with the html code for the element i want to test

Comment: which keyword is giving you that error?

Comment: @BryanOakley  ${TRAIN_LABEL}

Comment: @BryanOakley i tried those keywords above individually to do the same effect, the problems seems to be iin the variable

Comment: `${TRAIN_LABEL}` isn't a keyword, it's a variable. Some keyword is causing the error, we need to know which keyword.

Comment: @BryanOakley i know the key words are above (on the post), those are the keywords i tried to do the same effect, but it tested those separatedly and the test always stops on those specific keywords

Comment: You can't just show a bunch of keywords and say "one of them causes an error". Literally, if you are seeing an error in the log, it had to come from a single keyword. When I take the exact code you posted, put it into a syntactically correct test and run it, I do not get any errors.

Comment: @BryanOakley You not understanding, i tried those keywords because they have a similar effect but not at same time, and all of them dont work the way they should, they dont work at all, but this happens on this specific scenario,

Comment: You are leaving out significant information. I wrote a test with exactly your variable value and exactly your keywords, and none of them throw the error you say they do. They all worked just fine. When you run your test, the error _must_ come from a single keyword. You need to tell us which keyword is throwing that error. Without more specific information it is impossible for us to help you, because the code you've shown will not give the error you say it does.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley i update the post, i hope it is enough and it helps

Comment: When I add just enough code to be able to run your test, it does not throw the error you say it does. Perhaps you should run with the log level set to DEBUG so you can get a traceback. See [Debugging Problems](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#debugging-problems) in the robot framework user guide.

Comment: @BryanOakley  i also find this strange because i tried similar testes and it worked just fine, anyway thank you for you help...

Answer (score 1):

Information is limited, but I'll try:

You defined `${TRAIN_LABEL} = xpath=//*[@id='trainHeader'and contains(@data-train-id,'548')]`

If the above is in Variables section, it should have at least 2 whitespaces after the optional `=` sign that follows `${TRAIN_LABEL}`. If it's not in the Variables section, you cannot assign like this. You need to use `Set Variable` keyword:

```
${TRAIN_LABEL}    Set Variable    xpath=//*[@id='trainHeader'and contains(@data-train-id,'548')]
```